# how to make form validation laravel without submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, eloquent

I want to ask you about Laravel validation, I've finished laravel validation but have to click the data save button in form first before know the input error on form, and how to figure out the input error we've set in the controller without us clicking the submit button in form first? I have when submit will appear an eror message if I mis-input the error message I floated in sweet alert

for my form blade

```
 <form id="formpegawai" class="js-validation-bootstrap" method="post">

                            {{csrf_field()}}
                            <input name="_token" type="hidden" id="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
                            <div class="form-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {{--<label type="hidden" class="control-label col-md-3">Kode</label>--}}
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input name="kode" type="hidden" class="form-control" type="text"
                                               placeholder="Kode">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input name="user_id" type="hidden" class="form-control" type="text"
                                               placeholder="Kode">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <x></x>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="val-name">Nama<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama" name="nama"
                                               placeholder="Masukan Nama..." required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="val-name">Alamat<span
                                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="alamat" name="alamat"
                                               placeholder="Masukan Alamat...">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="val-name">Tempat Lahir<span
                                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tempat_lahir" name="tempat_lahir"
                                               placeholder="Masukan Tempat Lahir...">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="val-name">Tanggal Lahir<span
                                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="js-flatpickr form-control bg-white"
                                               id="Date" name="tgl_lahir"
                                               placeholder="Y-m-d">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="val-name">Pendidikan Terkahir<span
                                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <select class="form-control" id="pendidikan_terkahir"
                                                name="pendidikan_terkahir">
                                            <option value="0">Silahkan Pilih</option>
                                            <option value="SMA">SMA</option>
                                            <option value="SMK">SMK</option>
                                            <option value="S1">S1</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="val-name">Tahun Masuk</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tahun_masuk" name="tahun_masuk"
                                               placeholder="Masukan Tahun Masuk..." readonly>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="val-name">No Telp<span
                                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="no_telp" name="no_telp"
                                               placeholder="Masukan No Telpon...">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="val-name">Jenis Kelamin<span
                                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <select class="form-control" id="jkel" name="jkel">
                                            <option value="0">Silahkan Pilih</option>
                                            <option value="laki-laki">Laki-Laki</option>
                                            <option value="wanita">Wanita</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="val-name">Jabatan<span
                                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <select class="form-control" id="id_jabatan" name="id_jabatan">
                                            <option value="0">Silahkan Pilih</option>
                                            @foreach ($dataku as $data)
                                                <option value="{{ $data->id }}">{{$data->id }}
                                                    [{{ $data->jabatan}}]
                                                </option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="val-name">Status Keaktifan <span
                                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <select class="form-control" id="status" name="status">
                                            <option value="0">Silahkan Pilih</option>
                                            <option value="aktif">Aktif</option>
                                            <option value="tidak aktif">Tidak Aktif</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" onclick="reload();" class="btn btn-danger"
                                            data-dismiss="modal">
                                        Cancel
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

for my controller code

```
 public function simpanpegawai(Request $req)
    {
        $messages = [
            'nama.required' => 'Field Nama Gak Boleh Kosong',
            'nama.min' => 'Field nama tidak boleh kurang dari 5 kata',
            'nama.regex' => 'Field nama tidak boleh angka',
            'alamat.required' => 'Field Alamat Gak Boleh Kosong',
            'alamat.min' => 'Field alamat tidak boleh 5 kata',
            'tempat_lahir.required' => 'Field tempat lahir harus diisi !',
            'tempat_lahir.regex' => 'field Tempat lahir tidak boleh ada angka',
            'tgl_lahir.required' => 'Field Tanggal Lahir harus diisi !',
            'tgl_lahir.date' => 'Field Tanggal Lahir harus format tanggal!',
            'pendidikan_terkahir.not_in' => 'Field pendidikan terkahir Gak Boleh Kosong',
            'no_telp.required' => 'Field no telpon Gak Boleh Kosong',
            'no_telp.min' => 'Field no telpon Harus minimal 10 ',
            'jkel.not_in' => 'Field jenis kelamin harus diisi !',
            'id_jabatan.not_in' => 'Field jabatan harus diisi !',
            'status.not_in' => 'Field status harus diisi !',
            ];

        $validator = \Validator::make($req->all(), [
            'nama' => 'required|min:5|regex:/^[a-zA-Z]+(([\',. -][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$/',
            'alamat' => 'required|min:5',
            'no_telp' => 'required|min:10',
            'tempat_lahir' => 'required|min:5|regex:/^[a-zA-Z]+(([\',. -][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$/',
            'tgl_lahir' => 'required|date',
            'pendidikan_terkahir' => 'not_in:0',
            'jkel' => 'not_in:0',
            'id_jabatan' => 'not_in:0',
            'status' => 'not_in:0',
        ], $messages);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()->all()]);
        } else {
            $user = new \App\User;
            $user->name = $req->nama;
            $user->role = $req->id_jabatan;
            $user->username = $req->nama;
            $user->password = bcrypt($req->no_telp);
            $simpan = $user->save();


            $req->request->add(['user_id' => $user->id]);
            $pegawai = \App\PegawaiModel::create($req->all());
            if ($simpan == 1) {

                $status = "Tersimpan";

            } else {
                $status = "Gagal";
            }
            echo json_encode(array("status" => $status));
        }
    }
```

for my jquery

```
$.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#formpegawai').serialize(),
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.errors) {

                        jQuery.each(data.errors, function (key, value) {
                            swal({
                                title: "Pesan Eror",
                                text: value,
                                timer: 5000,
                                showConfirmButton: false,
                                type: "error"
                            })
                        });

                    } else {
                        swal({
                            text: data.status,
                            timer: 5000,
                            icon:"success",
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            type: "error"
                        })
                        $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
                    }
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58176972/how-do-i-validate-forms-in-laravel-by-not-clicking-submit-button

Answer (score -1):

> You can give validation without page refresh. If you use bootstrap
>   then you can use easily validator.js plugin.
>
> Validator.js plugin gives client side validation without page refresh.

Example how you can validate required field, email, min-length etc.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>
            Bootstrap Validation example using validator.js
        </title>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js">
        </script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.5/validator.min.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br/>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="panel panel-primary" style="width:750px;margin:0px auto">


              <div class="panel-heading">Bootstrap Validation example using validator.js</div>
              <div class="panel-body">


                <form data-toggle="validator" role="form">


                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label" for="inputName">Name</label>
                      <input class="form-control" data-error="Please enter name field." id="inputName" placeholder="Name"  type="text" required />
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" required>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="password" data-minlength="5" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" data-error="must enter minimum of 5 characters" placeholder="Password" required>
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label" for="inputName">BIO</label>
                      <textarea class="form-control" data-error="Please enter BIO field." id="inputName" placeholder="Cina Saffary" required=""></textarea>
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="form-group">
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                          Submit
                      </button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[See more](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/bootstrap-form-validation-example-with-demo-using-validatorjs-pluginexample.html)

[Bootstrap Validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-overview)

Comment: @AndrewLee what is written here, but don't skip Laravel (PHP - server side) validation.